Proper Curve fitting for Intensity Plots
I am doing image analysis by analysing the histogram of intensity values.
I get similar plots (2 sharp peaks and one flat peak in specific order).
I tried to model it using mixture of Gaussian but the results are not good. I have attached the images for reference. After BIC Scores analysis, I found that the knee is when I set the number of gaussians to 4.
Out of 5 cases tried, following 2 gave good results:


However, following 3 were incorrect in terms of their results:



Are there alternate/better methods to approximate the curves?
I tried changing the gaussian parameters, or suppressing the intensities sharpness by applying average filter over the image and then taking the plots. Still did not help.
I tried approaches in the following:
Curve fitting for n detected peaks and different intensity
I am looking for 3 different curves one for the two peaks that appear towards the end, one for the plateau like part in the starting and maybe 1 curve with high variance and low weight for the other noise stuff.
Any solution that uses traditional CV Methods OR the methods in machine learning are most welcome.
Edit:
Source of histograms
I am analysing the histograms that were generated after segmenting the intestines from a segmentation model on 3D CT Scan Images. For almost 100 images, I get the similar curves on manual inspection.
The first plateau is fat, the first peak ahead is the distribution of contents and the further next peak is the distribution of intestinal wall. X axis represents a linear function of HU (hounds field unit) values.

you really should provide some context/background on what generated the histograms (the images, the camera, the imaged object, the lighting, ...). -- the choice of model depends on what generated those histograms. you can always try good old polynomials. -- histograms look nearest-neighbor-resampled, like the source's contrast was messed with. you should avoid that. -- and you might wanna provide the data, in the spirit of a [mre]. otherwise, you might get shooed off to the [dsp.se] SE or perhaps [stats.se] SE (histgrams and MoGs is statistics)

Source of histograms
I am analysing the histograms that were generated after segmenting the intestines from a segmentation model.
The first plateau is fat, the first peak ahead is the distribution of contents and the further next peak is the distribution of intestinal wall. X axis represents a linear function of HU (hounds field unit) values.
I can't provide the exact data due to regulations. Though I can provide the (x,y) values for these specific graphs.

@Curious_To_Know I guess the language your are interested in is Python? In which case please add the tag as well.

You could try other peak functions too, like Extreme (https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Extreme-FitFunc#:~:text=Function.%20Brief%20Description.%20Particular%20case%20of%20extreme%20function,) because of the tail you have in the first peak. Do you have access to the software OriginLab? It can be quite convenient to use for this type of exploratory stuff, then you can code the results in Python and apply to the rest of your dataset.

First "good" result looks worse than last two "incorrect" ones. What is good what is bad here?

ok. So the curve in black is the actual histogram. I want to fit a curve to it.
Expecially I just want the curve to find the peaks to be right and the bell should take the shape of the mountains.
Red are the indivisual gaussians. Blue is the resulting curve.
You could see that in last two, there is a spurious gaussian curve appearing.

IDK, the last picture shows 4 gaussians and they look plausible to me. I can't eyeball how well they fit, but they certainly fit the data better than just gaussians 1,3,4. with the second to last, you could argue that the highest mode doesn't deserve two gaussians. how they're placed depends on the algorithm. you can whip up an interactive program and try your own hypothesis for the placement and shape of gaussians.

I would like to suggest Gaussian process regression for this problem.
I tried to generate the data sample below (a 2D NumPy array, two columns, N rows):

The code for running a Gaussian process regression using a RBF kernel is provided below:
def main() -> None:

    t = data[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
    u = data[:, 1].reshape(-1, 1)

    gp_regressor = train_gaussian_process(t, u)
    x = np.linspace(min(t), max(t), 400).reshape(-1, 1)
    mean = gp_regressor.predict(x)

    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))
    plt.scatter(t, u, label="Observations", s=0.1)
    plt.plot(x, mean, linewidth=1.2)
    plt.show()


def train_gaussian_process(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> GaussianProcessRegressor:
    """
    Train Gaussian Process.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : np.ndarray
    y : np.ndarray

    Returns
    -------
    GaussianProcessRegressor

    """
    kernel = RBF(length_scale=0.2)
    gaussian_process = GaussianProcessRegressor(
        kernel=kernel, alpha=1e-2, n_restarts_optimizer=9, random_state=42
    )
    gaussian_process.fit(x, y)
    return gaussian_process


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Here is the results (you have to finetune the parameters):


Thanks. Will try it out and share the results.

@Curious_To_Know my pleasure!
